# JavaScript jQuery issue with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, submit, rendering

I have a problem. I think it's because of the rendering but I don't know because that topic is new to me.

Okay, I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="/send-mail">
<input type="text" name="msg" value="">
<input type="submit" value="send that fancy mail">
</form>
```

Now i want to catch that submit using jQuery like:

```
$('[type=submit]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formHtml = $(this).parent().html();

    $.ajax({
        ..all these options..,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('form').html("sending mail");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('form').html(formHtml); // I think here's the problem...
        }     
    });
});
```

okay, that code works really good. It does what it should do. But, If I want to send a second request, the submit button doesn't work anylonger as intended. It tries to send the form using the default-action although I prevnted that - at least that's what I thought.

I did use google but I don't even know how to explain my problem.

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks a lot!

Greetz

Comment: submit events should be put on the form, not the button. This also helps since the form element itself doesn't get changed and therefore the event listener stays in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **.html()** you can use:

> [.clone(true)](https://api.jquery.com/clone/):  Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.
>
> [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):  Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

The event must be **click** if attached to submit button or **submit** if attached to the form.

The snippet:

```js
$('[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formHtml = $(this).closest('form').clone(true);
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $('form').html("sending mail");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success');
            $('form').replaceWith(formHtml); // I think here's the problem...
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" action="/send-mail">
    <input type="text" name="msg" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="send that fancy mail">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).on("click", "[type=submit]", function (e) {`  for dynamically created ekements   instead of  `$('[type=submit]').submit(function(e) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">` and add an `onclick` function like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="_submitForm()" value="send that fancy mail">
```

And then your js will be:

```
function _submitForm(){
var formHtml = $(this).parent().html();

    $.ajax({
        ..all these options..,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('form').html("sending mail");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('form').html(formHtml); // I think here's the problem...
        }     
    });
}
```

I hope that solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry but I should have added that calling a function didn't solve my problem :/